# Should Python rename files synchronously with a return from the blocking call?

Tags: python

On both Linux (5.15.0-58-generic) and Windows 10 operating systems, across multiple versions of Python 3 (3.8.8, 3.10.6), I encounter errors where renaming a file races with subsequent Python code which depend upon the rename having already occurred.  Consider the follow code snippet:

```
import importlib
import os
import pathlib
import time

# Find expanded cmdset specs.
#
aeplpath = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
expanded_csids = set()
for specfilename in aeplpath.glob('spec_*.py'):
    expanded_csids.add(specfilename.stem[5:])

# Rename and import expanded CommandSet spec.
#
oldcmdsets = {}                            # csid -> CommandSet
for csid in sorted(expanded_csids):
    print('import expanded', csid)

    backmodname = 'back_' + csid
    specmodname = 'spec_' + csid
    backpathname = aeplpath / (backmodname + '.py')
    specpathname = aeplpath / (specmodname + '.py')

    # Rename the original specs from spec_*.py to back_*.py if it is
    # to be reformatted and determine the appropriate original modname
    # to import
    #
    assert not backpathname.is_file(), f'{backpathname} already exists'
    specpathname.rename(backpathname)

    #time.sleep(.001)    # this demonstrates the problem is a race
    #os.sync()           # this seems to fix the problem

    # Import the old expanded CommandSet.
    #
    oldcmdsets[csid] = importlib.import_module(backmodname).cmdset
```

And the following error:

```
import expanded FW00734_02
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mike-hayward1/qaenv/ptee/aepl/./aeplreformat.py", line 155, in <module>
oldcmdsets[csid] = importlib.import_module(backmodname).cmdset    # type: ignore
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'back_FW00734_02'
```

See in the commented out code where slowing the Python execution down causes the problem to go away on my systems, although this is certainly no guarantee.  In fact on a Windows system I test with it can take up to 5 seconds to overcome the race with any degree of reliability.  The best solution I've found is to flush the file system as commented.

I do not particularly want to write an expensive function that poles the filesystem and sleeps repeatedly, waiting for the rename to have completed.  My current strategy is to rewrite my applications to perform all renames before code that depends then sync to give the filesystem as much time as possible to batch up and possibly even quiesce, then issue sync before accessing renamed files to force the barrier.

Does anyone know of a better/lighter weight way to synchronize the filesystem with a call to Python's 'rename'?

What do we need to do to update Python documentation to make developers aware that 'rename' is not universally synchronous with other subsequent file system operations and that to implement a reliable application, they may need to implement their own synchronization mechanism?

Comment: `os.rename()` is __definitely__ atomic on any POSIX-compliant filesystem on Linux. Which raises the question: When testing on Linux, which filesystem are the files being renamed located on?

Comment: Is this specifically related to renaming Python module files or does it occur with any files?

Comment: (Also, note that there are layers you can put on top of a POSIX-compliant filesystem that make it not so compliant anymore; for example, put a layering filesystem like AUFS on top of btrfs or ext4, and suddenly you have broken atomicity; so something can be correct when it runs on your host but broken when you run it in Docker)

Comment: This *might* have something to do with importlib caches. If you create or install new modules while your code is running, you need to call [`importlib.invalidate_caches`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.invalidate_caches) for that to work properly. If it's an importlib cache issue, I wouldn't expect a race condition, though.

Comment: You may want to try manually `open`ing the file with the new name, instead of trying to import it with `importlib.import_module`. If `open` fails, then it's very unlikely the problem has anything to do with the import system.

Comment: ...oh, right, (some of) the cached values are directory modification timestamps. That's why the race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the excellent comments we have a solution given the Python library 'cache' behavior.  I was unaware that Python was caching more than just imported modules.  It appears to be caching the associated packages / directories that modules reside in and not *reading through* on a module 'cache miss' as one might expect.

Here is the evidence that Python importlib is only reading through to the filesystem once in awhile instead of whenever there is a module cache miss.  A slight change to the code to open the file, read the contents as a string, and print out the length *before* even attempting to import the library was quick enough that the race condition still triggers.

```
specpathname.rename(backpathname)

with open(backpathname, 'r') as f:
    print(backpathname, len(f.read()))

# importlib.invalidate_caches()

# Import the old expanded CommandSet.
#
oldcmdsets[csid] = importlib.import_module(backmodname).cmdset
```

On my data set this results in output like so:

```
/home/mike-hayward1/qaenv/ptee/aepl/back_FW00704_01.py 280355
import expanded FW00704_06
/home/mike-hayward1/qaenv/ptee/aepl/back_FW00704_06.py 308299
import expanded FW00734_01
/home/mike-hayward1/qaenv/ptee/aepl/back_FW00734_01.py 2153
import expanded FW00734_02
/home/mike-hayward1/qaenv/ptee/aepl/back_FW00734_02.py 9758
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mike-hayward1/qaenv/ptee/aepl/./aeplreformat.py", line 156, in <module>
    oldcmdsets[csid] = importlib.import_module(backmodname).cmdset    # type: ignore
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'back_FW00734_02'
```

Uncommenting the line to allow the importlib cache to be 'invalidated' resolves the race on my system.

I am an expert in storage and I find this lack of read through to be rather weak semantics.  I do realize after reading the docs very closely that Python does not guarantee anything about the coherence of importlib cache with respect to the filesystem except at the point the cache is invalidated so this behavior is not technically a defect.  I would, however, suggest that importlib be improved to 'do the right thing' when a cache miss would otherwise occur.

A 'best effort' read through cache implementation would not impose a significant performance penalty as the required read through occurs only on unhappy path, and in fact would be significantly more efficient than requiring the user to invalidate the entire importlib cache before importing a module.  This should simplify and improve the correctness of any applications that create, modify, install, or relocate libraries on the fly.